# VB.net filter datagrid on the fly

Tags: vb.net, search, gridview, csv, filter

I am new to programming and especially VB and I am trying to make a CSV reader where I can filter all of the content with a single search box.  Here is the code I used to load my CSV file into a datagrid:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SetupDataGridView()
        'Dim csvpath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\csvtest.csv"
        Dim csvpath As String = "c:\songs.csv"
        Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(csvpath)
            MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
            Dim currentRow As String()
            While Not MyReader.EndOfData
                Application.DoEvents()
                Try
                    currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                    With songsDataGridView
                        .ColumnCount = 2
                        Dim row As String() = New String() {currentRow(0), currentRow(1)}
                        .Rows.Add(row)
                    End With
                Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                    MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & _
                      "is not valid and will be skipped.")
                End Try

            End While
        End Using
    End Sub
```

This loads artist and title into the gridview with 2 columns and I can click the column headers and sort just fine.  What I want to do now is use my search box (TextBox1) and when I type anything, have the results that do not match disappear leaving just my search term.  I want to match either artist or title.  Then, when you clear the searchbox, I want to go back to showing all of the contents of the CSV file (original gridview).

I have searched everywhere and can't find exactly what I want.  A lot of database and SQL stuff, but not what I want with a datagrid.

Does anyone have anything that might help?  Also, is the best way to handle this the way I am handling it?  It take a few seconds to load all of the entries to the gridview so I didn't know if it would be better to load them into an array first and filter that or how it should work.  There are 12,000 songs so it take a bit.  Would that be too large of an array?

so I guess I have a two-part question:

1. Am I doing it the most efficient/best way?
2. How do I filter results on demand (whether it's in my grid on through an array somehow).  Super new to programming, also.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You may try storing your data in a `DataTable` object rather than embedding it directly in the `DataGridView`.  Then link your `DataGridView`'s data source to `DataTable.DefaultView`.  You can then filter the table using `DefaultView.RowFilter` as demonstated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview.aspx).  Also, you can make use of the `TextBox.Changed` event to apply the filter based on the value entered.

Comment: Thank you, I am having a problem loading the CSV into the datatable.  The code appears to be different than loading it into the gridview.  Also, I am having a problem getting the gridview to filter.  Any chance you can post an example of what you mentioned above, please?  I'n not sure where to put the code that you are mentioning.    Since I don't have room to paste my code here, here is a link to a screenshot of it with the parts in question [link]http://tinyurl.com/7bnkwtx